# Alternative Reporting service of Crystal Report for MVC/.Net Core Projects in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-core, crystal-reports

I am facing some major issue regarding Crystal report versioning issue. I always try to keep myself updated with technology. I have some web applications those were build using Crystal Report version 15 and version 21 using visual studio 13 and visual studio 17. Its impossible to work on all these projects using same visual studio as different crystal report versions for crystal report for visual studio. every time i need to uninstall and install required crystal report version.

Now when I am trying to use visual studio 2022 then I need to use different crystal report service pack 32. And while using this I am unable to work on other projects. This versioning problem is also a great problem for Server.

**So I want to shift to another report service for new projects. What should I pick where I would get most of the features of Crystal report but different version will not be a problem? any suggestions?**

Comment: SSRS is also a good reporting service you can use.

Comment: @kgajjar20 , can I use most of the features of crystal report in SSRS? is there any versioning issue with visual studio?

Comment: @AI Masum 
Types of reports : Crystal Reports, SSRS, HTML reports, ActiveReports, XtraReports, Telerik Reports , Power BI Report.

I found Telerik Reports as best as per use but all others are also good.

In HTML or Crystal reports, you can do some optimizations for crystal reports to reduce the loading time.

With SSRS data sources can be shared or embedded while in Crystal it can only be embedded in the report.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports is was built back in the mid 90's using C++. Over the years we started using COM components and then when Microsoft introduced .NET Framework and wanted to drop COM support we dropped our COM Reporting engine and created our .NET components, of course too many Developers complained so MS continued supporting COM.
With that news we has spent too much time building our Framework components, which still uses COM wrappers.
Then MS introduced a "light" version of the Framework. CR still required the full version. Now MS has Core framework which is a different flavor, but CR is still using the same C++ stack so there is no option to use CORE, it's not 100% compatible.
We did provide a work around for multiple version Applications on the same PC for those who require it.
Go to my WIKI - https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads
On that page is a KBA on how to use a redirect for those app's that can't be updated for what ever reason.
Basically use the Redirect Command in the others \bin folder, just create an app.exe.config file and add the Redirect in it.
Install the updated version and modify the version in the config file.
This should allow any third party application to use the updated runtime.

If you find issues post to SAP Community for CR for VS and I'll look into it:
https://answers.sap.com/tags/01200615320800001270

Have a great day
Don SAP - Senior Support Engineer

Answer (score 0):

[Bold Reports](https://www.boldreports.com) is another option to consider.

Bold Reports uses the same Report Definition Language (RDL) as SSRS, and several customers have switched from Crystal Reports to Bold Reports. The product is built using .NET Core but can be used with any platform.

Note: I work for Syncfusion (the company behind Bold Reports).